Cannot open RTDB Stream using C in ESP32
I'm making an api wrapper for Firebase API using C and ESP32, I'm able to pull and push data to RTDB. Currently I've been struggling to stream data from RTDB.
This is the current code I have that is able to stream data from my custom sse_server that I made in Python, and a random url that streams an mp3 file.
void Firebase_listen(void *pvParameters)
{
    Firebase *fb = (Firebase *)pvParameters;
    response_buffer_t *response = malloc(sizeof(response_buffer_t));
    if (response == NULL) {
        ESP_LOGE(TAG, "Failed to allocate memory for response_buffer_t");
        return;
    }
    response->response_buffer = calloc(sizeof(char), 8192);
    if (response->response_buffer == NULL) {
        ESP_LOGE(TAG, "Failed to allocate memory for response buffer");
        free(response);
        return;
    }
    response->response_length = 0;
    response->buffer_size = 8192;

        // .url = firebase_build_request_url(fb, "cookies"),
        // .url = "http://192.168.188.96:5000/stream",
        // .url = "https://st01.sslstream.dlf.de/dlf/01/128/mp3/stream.mp3"

    esp_http_client_config_t config = {
        .url = "https://firebase_url/cookies.json",
        .event_handler = chunked_stream_response_handler,
        .method = HTTP_METHOD_GET,
        .timeout_ms = 0,
        .buffer_size = 8192,
        .buffer_size_tx = 8192,
        .keep_alive_enable = true,
        .user_data = response,
    };

    esp_http_client_handle_t client = esp_http_client_init(&config);
    esp_http_client_set_header(client, "Accept", "text/event-stream");
    esp_http_client_set_header(client, "Cache-Control", "no-cache");
    esp_http_client_set_header(client, "Connection", "keep-alive");

        esp_err_t err = esp_http_client_perform(client);
        if (err != ESP_OK) {
            ESP_LOGE(TAG, "HTTP client SSE error: %s", esp_err_to_name(err));
        }
        vTaskDelay(5000 / portTICK_PERIOD_MS);

    esp_http_client_cleanup(client);
    free(response->response_buffer);
    free(response);
}

static esp_err_t chunked_stream_response_handler(esp_http_client_event_t *evt) {
    response_buffer_t *response = (response_buffer_t *)evt->user_data;

    switch (evt->event_id) {
        case HTTP_EVENT_REDIRECT:
            ESP_LOGI(TAG, "HTTP_EVENT_REDIRECT");
        case HTTP_EVENT_ERROR:
            ESP_LOGI(TAG, "HTTP_EVENT_ERROR");
            break;
        case HTTP_EVENT_ON_CONNECTED:
            ESP_LOGI(TAG, "HTTP_EVENT_ON_CONNECTED");
            break;
        case HTTP_EVENT_HEADER_SENT:
            ESP_LOGI(TAG, "HTTP_EVENT_HEADER_SENT");
            break;
        case HTTP_EVENT_ON_HEADER:
            ESP_LOGI(TAG, "HTTP_EVENT_ON_HEADER, key=%s, value=%s", evt->header_key, evt->header_value);
            break;
        case HTTP_EVENT_ON_DATA:
            ESP_LOGI(TAG, "HTTP_EVENT_ON_DATA, len=%d, data=%s", evt->data_len, (char *)evt->data);
            if (!esp_http_client_is_chunked_response(evt->client)) {
                if (response->response_length + evt->data_len < response->buffer_size) {
                    memcpy(response->response_buffer + response->response_length, evt->data, evt->data_len);
                    response->response_length += evt->data_len;
                    response->response_buffer[response->response_length] = 0;

                    const char *line = response->response_buffer;
                    const char *next_line;
                    while ((next_line = strstr(line, "\n")) != NULL) {
                        size_t line_length = next_line - line;
                        if (line_length > 0 && strncmp(line, "data:", 5) == 0) {
                            // Skip "data: "
                            const char *message = line + 5;
                            ESP_LOGI(TAG, "Received data: %.*s", (int)(line_length - 5), message);
                        }
                        line = next_line + 1;
                    }
                    response->response_length = 0; // Reset buffer size after processing
                } else {
                    ESP_LOGE(TAG, "Buffer overflow, data is too large");
                }
            }
            break;
        case HTTP_EVENT_ON_FINISH:
            ESP_LOGI(TAG, "HTTP_EVENT_ON_FINISH");
            break;
        case HTTP_EVENT_DISCONNECTED:
            ESP_LOGI(TAG, "HTTP_EVENT_DISCONNECTED");
            break;
    }
    return ESP_OK;
}

And this is the current output I get:
 (7625) firebase_api: HTTP_EVENT_ON_CONNECTED
 (7635) firebase_api: HTTP_EVENT_HEADER_SENT
 (7665) firebase_api: HTTP_EVENT_ON_HEADER, key=Server, value=nginx
 (7665) firebase_api: HTTP_EVENT_ON_HEADER, key=Date, value=Mon, 15 Jul 2024 11:23:17 GMT
 (7675) firebase_api: HTTP_EVENT_ON_HEADER, key=Content-Type, value=text/event-stream; charset=utf-8
 (7685) firebase_api: HTTP_EVENT_ON_HEADER, key=Connection, value=close
 (7685) firebase_api: HTTP_EVENT_ON_HEADER, key=Cache-Control, value=no-cache
 (7695) firebase_api: HTTP_EVENT_ON_HEADER, key=Access-Control-Allow-Origin, value=*
 (7705) firebase_api: HTTP_EVENT_ON_HEADER, key=Strict-Transport-Security, value=max-age=31556926; includeSubDomains; preload
 (7715) firebase_api: HTTP_EVENT_ON_DATA, len=71, data=event: put
**data: {"path":"/","data":{"cookies":30,"currentValue":30}}**

ntent-Type: text/event-stream; charset=utf-8
Connection: close
Cache-Control: no-cache
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31556926; includeSubDomains; preload

Z␚�qD�yd����.hWe��h�+�@␘��c��ʱ�F$�z�R�␁�����q1FoX������Y;���<���-�Z�)��J�O�&M�a�l������`�ϓq[(�AR�␋l�␗��2=��L��?b��␃\6ج#ђ��␅␘�␂��/�E�hl�9_␗���9��L�␓`"�����8�G'Ug�!Y��␐_�4`��#␗���l���l��<�o����`���h␚ա��O[�x␌C�␆�␘ZPO��]��␏��P3ƙ��␟P!��G���w6]N�?�
 (12785) firebase_api: HTTP_EVENT_ON_FINISH
 (12785) firebase_api: HTTP_EVENT_DISCONNECTED
 (17785) firebase_api: HTTP_EVENT_DISCONNECTED

if I use another URL (Not Firebase) , the event never disconnects, and just keeps streaming data, I'm allowing full access in RTDB rules, so that is not the issue
Is there a header or something that I am missing here? I'm really desperate to move on, I've been stuck for more than a week on this.
Thanks for your help.
